# Azure Search v11: Indexing nullable Collection of Complex Type

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-sdk-.net

I'm updating the SDK for the **Azure Cognitive Search** service, from v10 to v11. I have followed all the steps in the guide in order to upgrade, however I have noticed a strange behavior about the indexing (merge or upload) operation: the **UploadDocumentAsync** (but also with other methods used to indexing data) operation fails when a property of type **Collection (Edm.ComplexType)** is null, with the following error:

**A node of type 'PrimitiveValue' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the contents of the property. However, a 'StartArray' node was expected json.**

```
IndexDocumentsResult response = await searchClient.UploadDocumentsAsync<T>(documents).ConfigureAwait (false);
```

With v10 this problem did not arise. A workaround I found is to set collections as empty arrays and not with null value, but I would like to find a better solution.

EDITED:
I upgraded from Microsoft.Azure.Search v10.1.0 to Azure.Search.Documents v11.1.1
Following an example of a generic T class used to indexing data:

```
public class IndexEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("@search.score")]
    public double SearchScore { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Key")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ComplexObj")]
    public ComplexType[] CollectionOfComplexType{ get; set; }

}
```

Following the definition of ModelObjectToIndex

```
public class ComplexType
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Basically when the **CollectionOfComplexType** property is null, I get the above error. If I set it as an empty array, the error does not occur, but as mentioned I don't like this solution, furthermore in the old version it was an allowed operation (the indexing was completed successfully)

Comment: Please format your question so it's easier to read,

Comment: @aybe is it now better?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the definition of T and the details of the documents instances? That will help us troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Definitely better

Comment: What version of Azure.Search.Documents are you using? I'm one of the developers on it, and we did have some problems with older versions that weren't expecting a literal `null` in the response, so the deserializing might be throwing on this case. And do you have an example of a document that exhibits you can sanitize and share?

Comment: @Heath I updated my question with the missing details.

Comment: @BruceJohnston updated question.

Comment: @MFF Can you provide more details about the error? If it came from an exception, can you share the stack trace? I think Heath and I are confused about whether the error originates on the client or the server.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. The SDK is sending a literal `null` in the request for a complex collection that is not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our Azure.Search.Documents behavior seems to have changed in this regard. I've opened https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/18169 to track resolution.

You can workaround this issue without initializing your collections to an empty array by passing in a `JsonSerializerSettings` that was similar to what we did in our older Microsoft.Azure.Search library, since it seems from using the `JsonPropertyAttribute` you're using `Newtonsoft.Json` (aka Json.NET) anyway:

1. Add a package reference to Microsoft.Azure.Core.NewtonsoftJson if you haven't already. It recently GA'd so you don't need to use a preview if you were, which I presume since `System.Text.Json` - our default serializer - would not have honored your property renames.
2. Pass in a `JsonSerializerSettings` before creating your `SearchClient` like so:

   ```cs
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       // Customize anything else you want here; otherwise, defaults are used.
       NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
   };

   var options = new SearchClientOptions
   {
       Serializer = new NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer(settings),
   };

   var searchClient = new SearchClient(options);
   ```

We'll discuss how to resolve this by default, if we even can. One big change from the older library is the ability to customize the serializer used. By default we use `System.Text.Json`, but we support other serializers including `Newtonsoft.Json`. If someone were to pass in their own settings - or even desire the defaults - changing that could be catastrophic. So I'm curious: if we at least documented this behavior change (perhaps on the `SearchClient` class remarks and/or `UploadDocuments` and related methods) and how to retain previous behavior, would that have helped or otherwise been satisfactory?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping. 
I'm agree with you: adding this behaviour change, or perhaps a section with a special focus on how to manage null literal values, can be very helpful.